# copy same file into multiple directories - permission denied error

Tags: unix

Please help me in solving the below issue:

I want copy a file say info.txt into multiples directories and their sub-directories .

I used this command:

1. go to parent directory.
2. `find . -type d -exec cp ./info.txt {}/ \;`

But I'm getting the below error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file /info.txt : permission denied.
```

Comment: Well you need permissions in all the directories you want to copy that file into...

Comment: Including '/'. Are you sure you want to do that? Anyway, this is off-topic for a programming community!

Comment: Thanks a lot MAt , I also changed the permissions by giving chmod -R 777 basic. Still I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have permission to copy to the root `/` directory. Are you sure you want to copy there?

Be aware that `find . -type d` will return the current directory (`.`), so copying `./info.txt` to the current directory doesn't make sense, because it already exists there.

If you want to ignore the current directory use:

```
find . -type d ! -name "." -exec cp ./info.txt {}/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dogbane. Yes I do not want copy the file into current directory. But even after trying your command. I got same error..

Comment: @saras try changing to `! -name "/"` instead.